# SQL filtering with lead/over - syntax error

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, filtering

I am attempting to filter out duplicate records using this query and leave only records where there was a change in the `JOB_TITLE_DESCRIPTION` field between the current and previous record but am receiving a syntax error about the window function.

```
select ASSOCIATE_ID, 
JOB_TITLE_DESCRIPTION,
POSITION_EFFECTIVE_DATE, 
Lead(JOB_TITLE_DESCRIPTION,1,'0') OVER (Order By ASSOCIATE_ID ASC, POSITION_EFFECTIVE_DATE DESC) AS PrevTitle,
(case when PrevTitle <> JOB_TITLE_DESCRIPTION then 'Y' end) as title_change_flag

from 
SENSITIVE_DATA.ADP.EMP_JOB_HISTORY

where title_change_flag = 'Y'
```

Error:

> SQL compilation error: Window function
> [LEAD(EMP_JOB_HISTORY.JOB_TITLE_DESCRIPTION, 1, '0') OVER (ORDER BY
> EMP_JOB_HISTORY.ASSOCIATE_ID ASC NULLS LAST,
> EMP_JOB_HISTORY.POSITION_EFFECTIVE_DATE DESC NULLS FIRST)] appears
> outside of SELECT, QUALIFY, and ORDER BY clauses.

Comment: Which RDBMS are you using? Please tag

Answer (score 1):

There are couple more critical bug in you SQL ignore the error:

You are using LEAD which get you the "next" but you call this previous title, so it seems you should be using LAG, now yes you have DATE DESC but that is a double negative, so if you stick to LAG and stand ASC date sorting less confusion.

AND in the LEAD you are ORDER BY the `associate_id` that MUST be a PARTITION BY because two employees titles are completely unrelated.

```
LAG(job_title_description,1,'0') over (partition by associate_id order by position_effective_date) as prevtitle
```

Now Snowflake allows you to chain logic expression in the same select, so you can generate `title_change_flag` BUT a WHERE clause is run before the SELECT (officailly, ableit SNOWFLAKE lets to define simple terms in the select and put those in the WHERE) but LAG/LEAD is not simple

So this is valid (the CTE is just for dummy data):

```
with emp_job_history(associate_id, job_title_description, position_effective_date) as (
    select * from values
    (1, 'title1', '2000-01-01'::date),
    (1, 'title2', '2010-01-01'::date),
    (2, 'title1', '2000-01-01'::date),
    (2, 'title1', '2010-01-01'::date)
)
select 
    associate_id, 
    job_title_description,
    position_effective_date, 
    lag(job_title_description,1,'0') over (partition by associate_id order by position_effective_date) as prevtitle
    ,(case when prevtitle <> job_title_description then 'Y' end) as title_change_flag
from emp_job_history
--where title_change_flag = 'Y'
order by 1,3
```

which generates:

| ASSOCIATE_ID | JOB_TITLE_DESCRIPTION | POSITION_EFFECTIVE_DATE | PREVTITLE | TITLE_CHANGE_FLAG |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | title1 | 2000-01-01 | 0 | Y |
| 1 | title2 | 2010-01-01 | title1 | Y |
| 2 | title1 | 2000-01-01 | 0 | Y |
| 2 | title1 | 2010-01-01 | title1 | null |

You can however use QUALIFY to run a second filter after all the agregation has happened with allows avoiding the sub-select, thus:

```
select 
    associate_id, 
    job_title_description,
    position_effective_date, 
    lag(job_title_description,1,'0') over (partition by associate_id order by position_effective_date) as prevtitle
    ,(case when prevtitle <> job_title_description then 'Y' end) as title_change_flag
from emp_job_history
QUALIFY title_change_flag = 'Y'
order by 1,3
```

gives:

| ASSOCIATE_ID | JOB_TITLE_DESCRIPTION | POSITION_EFFECTIVE_DATE | PREVTITLE | TITLE_CHANGE_FLAG |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | title1 | 2000-01-01 | 0 | Y |
| 1 | title2 | 2010-01-01 | title1 | Y |
| 2 | title1 | 2000-01-01 | 0 | Y |

but it gets better, if you don't want to see the column `TITLE_CHANGE_FLAG`
you can move that into the QUALIFY:

```
select 
    associate_id, 
    job_title_description,
    position_effective_date, 
    lag(job_title_description,1,'0') over (partition by associate_id order by position_effective_date) as prevtitle
from emp_job_history
QUALIFY prevtitle <> job_title_description
order by 1,3
```

| ASSOCIATE_ID | JOB_TITLE_DESCRIPTION | POSITION_EFFECTIVE_DATE | PREVTITLE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | title1 | 2000-01-01 | 0 |
| 1 | title2 | 2010-01-01 | title1 |
| 2 | title1 | 2000-01-01 | 0 |

But wait there is more, perhaps you don't even want to see the LAG value, move that to the qualify also..

```
select 
    associate_id, 
    job_title_description,
    position_effective_date
from emp_job_history
QUALIFY job_title_description <> lag(job_title_description,1,'0') over (partition by associate_id order by position_effective_date)
order by 1,3
```

| ASSOCIATE_ID | JOB_TITLE_DESCRIPTION | POSITION_EFFECTIVE_DATE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | title1 | 2000-01-01 |
| 1 | title2 | 2010-01-01 |
| 2 | title1 | 2000-01-01 |

Answer (score 0):

I guess the problem is that you are trying to access an alias name in the same select clause where you define it (PrevTitle). This is not allowed in SQL. (The error message had hence better been "unknown column prevtitle" or the like.)

Here is a solution with a subquery:

```
select associate_id, job_title_description, position_effective_date
from
(
  select 
    associate_id, 
    job_title_description,
    position_effective_date, 
    lag(job_title_description, 1, 'no job') over (partition by associate_id order by position_effective_date) as prevtitle
  from sensitive_data.adp.emp_job_history
) with_prevtitles
where prevtitle <> job_title_description 
order by associate_id, position_effective_date;
```

Here is the same query with `QUALIFY`:

```
select associate_id, job_title_description, position_effective_date
from sensitive_data.adp.emp_job_history
qualify job_title_description <> lag(job_title_description, 1, 'no job') over (partition by associate_id order by position_effective_date)
order by associate_id, position_effective_date;
```